Override value in pydantic model with environment variable
I am building some configuration logic for a Python 3 app, and trying to use pydantic and pydantic-settings to manage validation etc. I'm able to load raw settings from a YAML file and create my settings object from them. I'm also able to read a value from an environment variable. But I can't figure out how to make the environment variable value take precedence over the raw settings:
import os
import yaml as pyyaml
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class FooSettings(BaseSettings):
    foo: int
    bar: str
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_prefix='FOOCFG__')


raw_yaml = """
foo: 13
bar: baz
"""

os.environ.setdefault("FOOCFG__FOO", "42")

raw_settings = pyyaml.safe_load(raw_yaml)
settings = FooSettings(**raw_settings)

assert settings.foo == 42

If I comment out foo: 13 in the input yaml, the assertion passes. How can I make the env value take precedence?

Are you sure you want the environment to take precedence? While not ubiquitous, it is very common for environment variables to have the lowest precedence (typically, the ordering is built-in defaults, then environment variables, then configuration files, then command line options). Deviating from this convention can be surprising.
You could get the behavior you want for a specific field by adding a field validator that checks for the appropriate environment variable and uses that value in preference to an existing value if it is avaiable. Something like:
import os
import yaml as pyyaml
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
from pydantic import field_validator


class FooSettings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_prefix="FOOCFG__")

    foo: int
    bar: str

    @field_validator("foo", mode="after")
    @classmethod
    def validate_foo(cls, val):
        '''Always use the value from the environment if it's available.'''
        if env_val := os.environ.get(f"{cls.model_config['env_prefix']}FOO"):
            return int(env_val)

        return val


raw_yaml = """
foo: 13
bar: baz
"""

os.environ.setdefault("FOOCFG__FOO", "42")

raw_settings = pyyaml.safe_load(raw_yaml)
settings = FooSettings(**raw_settings)

assert settings.foo == 42

If you wanted to do this for all fields, you could use a model validator instead. Maybe something like this?
    @model_validator(mode="after")
    @classmethod
    def validate_foo(cls, data):
        for field in cls.model_fields:
            env_name = f'{cls.model_config["env_prefix"]}{field.upper()}'
            if env_val := os.environ.get(env_name):
                setattr(data, field, type(getattr(data, field))(env_val))

        return data


I'll take a look at the model validator approach, though at that point it seems like pydantic-settings isn't really doing much for me.

And honestly this isn't a great solution, since it bypasses any validation on the individual fields. If you can figure out how to adapt to the conventional value precedence everything ends up being much simpler.

This is the first time I've seen anything deviate from "commandline args > environment variables > config file", but it's a big world out there ‍♂️. I think what I have to do is just not use pydantic-settings and write my own thing to update the raw settings after deserializing but before instantiating the pydantic model. I think this will solve a couple other issues I had too, so maybe for the best

Just to pick a relevant example, pip docs state: "Precedence / Override order:
Command line options override environment variables, which override the values in a configuration file. "

But envvars usually have high precedence, only cmd flags should override them. That's what I see in almost every tool, and there's a good reason for that: exporting an envvar for one-off operation is easier than editing the config file.

Have a look at https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/pydantic_settings/#other-settings-source
It allows you to customize your config sources. For env > yaml:
from typing import Tuple, Type

from pydantic import BaseModel

from pydantic_settings import (
    BaseSettings,
    PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
    SettingsConfigDict,
    YamlConfigSettingsSource,
)


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    foo: int
    bar: str

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(yaml_file='config.yml')

    @classmethod
    def settings_customise_sources(
        cls,
        settings_cls: Type[BaseSettings],
        init_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
        env_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
        dotenv_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
        file_secret_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
    ) -> Tuple[PydanticBaseSettingsSource, ...]:
        return (init_settings, env_settings, YamlConfigSettingsSource(settings_cls),)

